# Material datepicker with specific timezone

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my angular 5 application I am using some [datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api) and I need that when someone selects some date from the datepicker this date has to be in a specific timezone (italy) not in the browser/system timezone, because I need to set a specific date/hour in the destination country.

Is it possible?
this is my datepicker:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput #date required formControlName="entryDate" name="entryDate" (dateChange)="fareHandler()" [matDatepicker]="picker" (click)="picker.open()" placeholder="{{ 'ticket.new.labels.entrydate' | translate }}">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker" [disabled]="abil"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is no quick-fix -- you'll have to do a bit of work to incorporate this package into your work -- but you probably should look into Moment Timezone: https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: I already have it, but datepicker select always a date based on system timezone

Comment: Any luck with this?  I'm running into the same problem and can not find a solution.

Comment: did you try by using custom Moment Timezone pipe?